# "Facebook at work" What is the Authentication API ? How to use it?

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

I'm working with a company which use **Facebook at work** "companyName.facebook.com". (fb@w, facebookatwork)

I need to create a third party application which can **authenticate each User with their (fb@W) "Facebook at work" standalone account** :

On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-at-work/authentication/facebook

[image]

*The authentication doesn't work with the current FB API* 
I didn't find any information (or examples) concerning the authentication with the fb@w API.

I also tried to inspect what does the fb@w web (https://fb.facebook.com/) authentication and found a post request : 

`'https://companyName.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=101'`

with three params :

`email : email@companyMail.com,
pass : password,
lsd : AVtApDPM //I don't know what that is and how to generate it...`

But unfortunately I got a 302 error, and I can't use this as a proper API....

Do you have any information concerning the fb@w authentication ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunately  : No